# android-How to show or hide status bar between fragments on same activity

Tags: android, statusbar

In my app in some fragments I want to display status bar and in some fragments I want to hide the status bar. These all fragments are attached to the same activity.

I am able to hide the status bar for fragment ONE and show the status bar for fragment Two

The problem I am facing is when I navigate back from fragment TWO to the fragment ONE then status bar is not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the system bars in your activity's onCreate() method and the user presses back, the system bars will reappear. When the user reopens the fragment, onCreate() won't get called, so the system bars will remain visible. If you want system UI changes to persist as the user navigates in and out of your activity, set UI flags in onResume() or onWindowFocusChanged().

You can find more info here:

http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

I hope it is useful.